# LT1711 maximum supply voltage and maximum input voltage

Tags: power-supply, comparator

I want to include the LT17111 comparator into my design but I cannot get some clear information from the datasheet [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/171112f.pdf).

1. Can I power it from 12V and GND?
2. Can I put a signal with 8V amplitude into one of its inputs?

Thank you!

Comment: "*they operate over a single supply voltage range
from 2.4V to 12V or from ±2.4V to ±6V dual supplies.*" - what is not clear in it? Or in "*Differential Input Voltage ..... ±12.6V*" ?

Comment: @EugeneSh., at the same time, there's a "max positive supply voltage" spec on page 3 given as 7 V.

Comment: @ThePhoton Interesting. Do you think it's a typo? Not the first time with LT I am seeing one...

Comment: That is what I was confused about. Absolute maximum rating is 12.6V but in the same time V+ Max is 7V. Input is tied to this too because it is V+ + 0.1.

Comment: Absolute maximum is the maximum without damaging the chip. There's no promise the chip will work normally at or near those limits.

Comment: The confusion is because the page 1 text doesn't match the electrical characteristics specs. If it were me, I'd call Linear and ask them to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I power it from 12V and GND?

The supply voltage from \$ V^+  \$ to \$ V^-\$ is 12.6V, so yes. This is found in the absolute maximum ratings section. If you violate the conditions in the absolute maximum ratings, you will have loss of functionality or destroy the part. This is the first thing you should read when looking at integrating a part into a design. Staying withing the absolute maximum ratings *does not mean* the part will function the way you want it to.

> Can I put a signal with 8V amplitude into one of its inputs?

Yes as long as you don't exceed ±12.6 between pins and don't exceed the current.

> Differential Input Voltage ................................... ±12.6V
>   Input and Latch Current ..................................... ±10mA

You also have a common mode range to worry about.

Comment: The +/- 12.6 differential input voltage spec is an absolute maximum rating. You "can" apply such a voltage to the chip without damaging the chip. But there's no promise that the chip will function normally under those conditions.

Comment: Hence the statement "loss of functionality or destroy the part"

Comment: My point is you can have loss of functionality without violating the absolute max ratings. If you want to be sure of functionality you have to obey the recommended operating conditions.

Comment: Most every manufactuer gives this warning in their datasheet: "Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause permanent damage to the device."